# json representation for iphone localization app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I  have a write a simple json representing the position of same places like:

```
{
        lat = "41.653048";
        long = "-0.880677";
        name = LIMPIA;
    },
```

In iphone programming, my app is able to show the position on the map. My question is about how replicate the same on multiple position. For example with a json like:

```
    {
    lat = "41.653048";
    long = "-0.890677";
    name = name1 ;
},

    {
    lat = "41.653048";
    long = "-0.890677";
    name = name2;
},
```

How i can able to know the number of itemes? I have to change the json adding anything else in representation?or i have to completelin change it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to represent a list of locations in json?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a JSON array:

```
[
  {
    lat = "41.653048";
    long = "-0.890677";
    name = name1 ;
  },
  {
    lat = "41.653048";
    long = "-0.890677";
    name = name2;
  },
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to modify my php code that write the json. I supose that parsing that joson I m be able to know , for ejxample how many items the json has.

Comment: actually my json is:  [{"id":"0","nombre":"LIMPIA","lat":"41.653048","long":"-0.880677"},{"id":"1","nombre":"LIMPIA2","lat":"41.653048","long":"-0.890677"}] but i don'know hoy parse the items for example with "for" loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but it seems like you want to know how to best include multiple points in one JSON object?

```
{ 
  "locations": 
   [ 
      {
        lat = "41.653048";
        long = "-0.890677";
        name = name1 ;

      }, 
      {
        lat = "41.653048";
        long = "-0.890677";
        name = name2;

      }
   ] 
}
```

Comment: Yes, i need to kwon the efient way to represent multiple location (also in order to parse it in xcode). thank u so much, i try ti modify my php code that write the json

Comment: actually my json is:[{"id":"0","nombre":"LIMPIA","lat":"41.653048","long":"-0.880677"},{"id":"1","nombre":"LIMPIA2","lat":"41.653048","long":"-0.890677"}] how can i obtain  your representation?  (I have used the json_encode of:     $data[0] = array("id"=> "0", "nombre" => "LIMPIA", "lat" => "41.653048", "long"=>"-0.880677");
)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean to parse or write JSON from/to objects. I outline both.

```
@interface MyPointModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation MyPointModel

@synthesize latitude, longitude, name;

@end
```

**Parsing**

(and where ever you do the parsing)

```
@implementation ParsingController

...
- (NSArray *)buildArrayOfMyPointModelWithString:(NSString *)json {

    NSArray *array = [jsonParser.objectWithString:json error:NULL];
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfMyPointModel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (id jsonElement in array) {
        MyPointModel *m = [[MyPointModel alloc] init];

        m.latitude = [jsonElement valueForKey:@"lat"];
        m.longitude = [jsonElement valueForKey:@"long"];
        m.name = [jsonElement valueForKey:@"name"];

        [arrayOfMyPointModel addObject:m];
    }

    return (NSArray *)arrayOfMyPointModel;
}
```

**Writing**

(a sample array of my point)

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
MyPointModel *m1 = [[MyPointModel alloc] init];
MyPointModel *m2 = [[MyPointModel alloc] init];
m1.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.1];
m1.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01];
m1.name = @"M1";
m2.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.2];
m2.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.02];
m2.name = @"M2";
[a addObject:m1];
[a addObject:m2];

- (NSString *)buildJsonStringWithMyPointModelArray:(NSArray *)array {

    SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];

    return [writer stringWithObject:array];
}
```

Comment: Yes , my probles is parse the multiple position. I will try you solution, although the "    NSArray *array = [jsonParser.objectWithString:json error:NULL];
" does't compile. Tx so much